# How to handle video calls on Asterisk with Sipdroid?

Tags: video, config, sip, asterisk

I'm currently able to send video from one soft phone to another but I'm not able to receive the video. So I'm only seeing the video that's being sent from the same phone sending it and not seeing the other phone's video. I know it's possible but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I already added videosupport=yes in the general section of my sip.conf as well as allowing some other codecs. Anything I'm missing? Do I need to add anything to extensions.conf? I haven't touched that ever since I decided I wanted to add video calls.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As of 2010-12-18 Sipdroid does NOT support SIP video calling.

They advertise a "video" feature but it's a custom thing that only works with PBXes.com, and nothing else.

See this bug report for details:
http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/detail?id=223